# SQL WHERE column values into capital letters

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

Let's say I have the following entries in my database:

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | John Doe |
| 13 | Mary anne |
| 13 | little joe |
| 14 | John doe |

In my program I have a string variable that is always capitalized, for example:

`myCapString = "JOHN DOE"`

Is there a way to retrieve the rows in the table by using a WHERE on the name column with the values capitalized and then matching `myCapString`?

In this case the query would return two entries, one with id=12, and one with id=14

A solution is **NOT** to change the actual values in the table.

Comment: Don't know why table is malformed. It looks correct in editing mode.

Comment: Use a case insensitive collation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general solution in Postgres would be to capitalize the `Name` column and then do a comparison against an all-caps string literal, e.g.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE UPPER(Name) = 'JOHN DOE';
```

If you need to implement this is Knex, you will need to figure out how to uppercase a column.  This might require using a raw query.